# Canvases are not lining up correctly in tkinter using rowspan

Tags: python, tkinter

I have some code in python mainly using the library tkinter for a Hangman game:

```py
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import time

pause=500

class Graphics(Canvas):

    pics = {
        '1':'backgrounds/step1.png',
        '2':'backgrounds/step2.png',
        '3':'backgrounds/step3.png',
        '4':'backgrounds/step4.png',
        '5':'backgrounds/step5.png',
        '6':'backgrounds/step6.png',
        '7':'backgrounds/step7.png',
        '8':'backgrounds/step8.png',
        '9':'backgrounds/step9.png',
        '10':'backgrounds/step10.png',
        '11':'backgrounds/step11.png',
        '12':'backgrounds/step12.png'
    }

    def __init__(self, master):

        self.width=500
        self.height=550

        Canvas.__init__(self, master, bg='saddle brown', width=self.width, height=self.height, highlightthickness=0)

        # self.step = '1'
        # self.createImage(self.step)

    def createImage(self,picName,size=()):
        if size==():
            size=(self.width,self.height)
        filename = self.pics[picName]
        self.im = Image.open(filename)
        self.resizePic(size)
        self.img=ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.im)
        self.pic = self.create_image(self.width/2,self.height/2,anchor=CENTER,\
                                     image=self.img)

    def resizePic(self,size):
        self.im = self.im.resize(size,Image.ANTIALIAS)

    def nextStep(self):
        if self.step=='6':
            self.after(pause, self.master.welcome)
            return
        self.step = str(int(self.step)+1)
        self.delete(self.pic)
        self.createImage(self.step)
        self.after(pause, self.nextStep)

class TEXT(Canvas):

    def __init__(self, master, width, height, text):

        Canvas.__init__(self, bg='black',width=width,height=height,highlightthickness=0)
        self.text = self.create_text(width/2,height/2,anchor = "center", text=text, fill='white', font = ("Arial", 24))


class Hangman(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):

        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid()

        self.graphics = Graphics(self)
        self.graphics.grid(row=0,column=0,rowspan=10)

      #  self.after(pause, self.graphics.nextStep)
        self.after(pause, self.welcome)

        
    def welcome(self):
        self.welc = TEXT(self, 500, 55*3, "Welcome")
        self.welc.grid(row=0,column=1,rowspan=3)
        self.after(pause, self.to)
        

    def to(self):
        self.Hto = TEXT(self, 500, 55*3, "to")
        self.Hto.grid(row=3,column=1,rowspan=3)
        self.after(pause, self.hman)

    def hman(self):
        self.Hman = TEXT(self, 500, 55*4, "HANGMAN!")
        self.Hman.grid(row=6,column=1,rowspan=4)

    def removeWELC(self):
        self.delete(self.welcome)
        # self.delete(self.)


def play_hangman():
    root = Tk()
    root.title='Hangman'
    game = Hangman(root)
    root.mainloop()

play_hangman()
```

For the purpose of my question, the pictures are not needed. Anyway, I want the words, "Welcome" "to" "Hangman" appear after pauses of 1/2 seconds. The timing and everything is correct.

However, instead of the three Canvases lining up correctly right next to the 'brown rectangle', one of them is oddly centered to the right of it, and the other two are below it. why is this happening like this?

Comment: You need to create a [MCVE]. Right now, the code isn't runnable because there are many things that are undefined, such as the images. See [ask] and [tour] for more help with writing questions.

Comment: um...I made the code so that it wouldn't use the images...it is easily runable

Comment: Yeah, but when I run it on my computer, it says the images are undefined. Perhaps I need to get out of my enviroment.

Comment: idk...but the code never actually uses any of the images, so it shouldn't know whether or not the images are valid.

Comment: It's working now, I had some extra code that I wrote myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you forgot to assign `master` to `Canvas.__init__(...)` inside `TEXT.__init__()` function.

Change below:

```
class TEXT(Canvas):
    def __init__(self, master, width, height, text):
        Canvas.__init__(self, bg='black',width=width,height=height,highlightthickness=0)
```

to:

```
class TEXT(Canvas):
    def __init__(self, master, width, height, text):
        Canvas.__init__(self, master, bg='black',width=width,height=height,highlightthickness=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to tell your frame how many rows it is going to have.

Change:

```py
class Hangman(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):

        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid()
```

to:

```py
class Hangman(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):

        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid(rowspan=10)
```

The reason is that the grid [ignores empty rows and colums](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm).